# evaluation of a probability

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, evaluation

Hy my program i running only for one value but i want to run this for several values By addind result of previous one at a same time.... my program is

```
SeedRandom[1]
y = RandomInteger[100, {16, 16}]
a = {1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {1, 3}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {6, 7}, \
{1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 6, 7}, {3, 6, 7}, {1, 3, 6, 7};
x = y[[Join[a, a + 8], Join[a, a + 8]]];
(-2 (1 - v))^1/Sqrt[Det[x + I]]
```

,  I is a identity matrix of corresponding size of x ,This program giving error not picking values of a one by one .. What Should be possible error in my program

Comment: What is `a` suppose to be? Maybe you mean `a = {{1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {1, 3}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {6, 
    7}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 6, 7}, {3, 6, 7}, {1, 3, 6, 7}}`, but the rest doesn't make sense. Moreover, `I` is the built-in symbol for the complex unit (sometimes falsely denoted by $\sqrt{-1}$).

Comment: sorry I is identity matrix  and a is a list of submatrix that can extracted from a y calculate probability

Comment: Please try this: `SeedRandom[1]; y=RandomInteger[100,{16,16}]; a={{1},{3},{6},{7},{1,3}, {1,6},{1,7},{3,6},{3,7},{6,7},{1,3,6},{1,3,7},{1,6,7},{3,6,7},{1,3,6,7}}; Map[(Print["# is ", #]; x=y[[Join[#, #+8],Join[#, #+8]]]; Print["x is ", x]; (-2(1-v))^(1/Sqrt[Det[x+IdentityMatrix[Length[x]]]]))&, a]` and see if each step of this is correctly doing what you want. `Map` uses each entry in `a` one at a time and names that entry `#`. If not then please explain how someone who does not understand what you want would be able to do each step of your calculation and give you the correct result. Thanks

Comment: Sir Bill  program evaluating the formula but does not adding them

Comment: please  bill  sir give me any idea to add all results at end